# rails from fields without model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form for creating a new User.

_**form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@practice) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
     <b>Name:   </b>
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </div>
   <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Now i want to add a field like the name one again. But now you should not edit the content, but select one of three radio buttuns, which will change the value via jquery.

How can you add fields without a model to this form, and change the value of the text_field ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for(:controller, url:controller_path) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :name %>
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </div>
   <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: in my example (practices) what have :controller and :controller_path have to be?

Comment: so :practices and url:practices_path  ?

Comment: its depend what's your controller name, and your path in which you wanna post your attributes. If it's practice then it's gonna work

Comment: so i want to paste them to create_practice_path, don't I?